# My Lumia 435 can share cellular Internet but cannot use it for itself!

Tags: cellular-data, dual-sim

My Lumia 435 Dual SIM can share its cellular over hotspot, and I can use the shared Internet on my other devices smoothly and easily and with high speed, however it cannot use it for itself. Tested for both SIMs (set for data connection), this has annoyed me when I had Windows Phone 8.1 installed and currently Windows 10 Mobile (build 10.0.10586.11). Some messaging apps work however, for example I can receive messages and send them in text, but still cannot download or upload multimedia or surf web (formerly on Internet Explorer and now on Microsoft Edge).

Comment: Do you have a data plan set up fro your primary SIM, do you have a secondary SIM installed?

Comment: I have two sims installed, but have no idea what data plan is. If it is  data pack purchased from operator, yes I have.

Comment: Who's your carrier? Have you made sure you SIM internet and MMS APN's are correct?

Comment: @Shawn it's Irancell (an MTN subsidiary) for SIM 2 and MCI (local telecom provider) for SIM 1. Actually I have Internet access as my other devices using the shared Internet have Internet connectivity, but the device itself seems to be unable to use it.